# How to handle TimeoutExceptions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, connection-timeout

I am using Entity Framework 6 and my application communicates with the database a lot. In most circumstances, the connection is good and everything works as intended. However, I know that the client's database server can sometimes get a little slow, which might cause timeout exceptions in some situations. As far as I can tell, whenever this happens my entire application will crash, which seems ridiculous when I could simply inform the user to try a particular query again later. I realize I could wrap all of my EF queries in a try/catch, but I would have to do that for literally hundreds of queries and updates, making the code much harder to read.

Is there a way that I can handle TimeoutExceptions in EF without littering my code with try/catch statements everywhere?

Comment: try to set it like `ObjectContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;`

Comment: @RahulHendawe I don't want to modify the actual command timeout, I know how to do that. My problem is when (for example) the server is overloaded with requests and can't respond in a reasonable time frame. I don't want to raise the command timeout to 10 minutes, that's not user friendly.

Comment: refer this article on code project [Implementing Connection Resiliency with Entity Framework 6](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758469/Implementing-Connection-Resiliency-with-Entity-Fra)

Comment: @RahulHendawe Thank you, this link is helpful.